# Pushing View Controller Fails to Animate

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit, segue

Greeting,

I am struggling with a project, because the segue between a `UITableViewController` (which lives in a navigation controller) and a custom `UIViewController` is not animating.

The checkbox in Storyboard clearly states "animates", the kind is "Show (e.g. Push)". Yet, when the segue is performed, there is no animation. After some testing, I have found that manually calling `UINavigationController` `pushViewController(destination, animated: true)` does *not* animate either.

The destination View Controller contains a couple views that do some custom drawing.

What could I be doing wrong ?

Cheers,

Alexandre.

Comment: I would clean out DerivedData (exit Xcode and `rm -frd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`) -- if that doesn't work -- do other animations on your phone work (in other apps?)

Comment: @LouFranco I tried, didn't work. Yes, other animations work throughout, and this is reproducible on two different Mac simulators, and two different iPhone 6.

Comment: @DamianRzeszot What in particular ? Neither view controllers override any methods relating to segues, except the table view controller overrides `shouldPerformSegue`. 
Is that wrong ? I am also not subclassing `UIStoryBoardSegue`

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what you are doing. What is the flow of your program? Are you doing any potentially long running calculations in viewWillAppear()?

Comment: Are you adding ui elements in viewDidLoad off the main thread by accident? If you could post a little more information about your code it would be much easier to pick apart what could be wrong.

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson We are not doing any multithreading yet. Also, I have ran through the code, and I am not overriding `viewWillAppear()` anywhere. Any code that could potentially be "long" is done in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Thank you for your time guys, we've been struggling with this for the past two days, researching in the docs and finding no one with a similar problem...

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't particularly clear there reading it back. All I was saying is that there a lot of reasons this kind of thing could happen, either as an error with Xcode or with your code itself. Either way it's very hard to try to get to a solution without some more information about the code related to the problem.

Comment: Would you mind posting your view did load code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109452/discussion-between-alexandre-cassagne-and-olivier-wilkinson).

Comment: I think that could help (by the way I had a similar problem and it was due to a long running piece of code being run before viewDidAppear())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AlexandreCassange and I managed to find the problem in chat, but for anyone who is finding a similar problem here was the solution:

The problem was that while the viewController was being loaded (before viewDidAppear() is called) some code for laying out a CALayer was taking a too long and effectively blocked the animation.

The process to debug this problem is as such:

Check for any code that runs before viewDidAppear() that may take a long time and comment it out, then check if the animation is working. Do this one block of code at a time so you can find exactly where the offending code is. This is how Alexandre found it himself.

Alternatively, use Instruments (time profiler) to check for any long running code that occurs during the initialisation of the destination viewController.

Sometimes though this could happen because the viewControllers initialisation is complex, and while each individual code block runs relatively quickly, together the process is too slow. In this case use the time profiler to optimise your initialisation. I recommend watching the WWDC video [Profiling In-Depth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/412/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The exact part that was wasting time was a CATransaction within a didSet for a property. Removed it and the problem disappeared.

Comment: No problem at all :)